# modelling data as a multivariate time series in r

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to know the r code to simulate a multivariate time series data in r. To be precise I would like to simulate the kind of time series data subset found in the Genenet  Package e.g

```
library(Genenet)
data(arth800)
subset = c(60, 141, 260, 333, 365, 424, 441, 512, 521, 578, 789, 799)
arth12 = arth.expr[, subset]
```

I would like the simulated data to look like the one shown below

```
> str(arth12)
 num [1:22, 1:12] 6.59 6.33 7.12 6.9 7.22 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:22] "0-1" "0-2" "1-1" "1-2" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:12] "265768_at" "263426_at" "260676_at" "258736_at"

> arth12[1:8,1:8]
    265768_at 263426_at 260676_at 258736_at 257710_at 255764_at 255070_at 253425_at
0-1  6.589464  8.708049  6.802193  2.560715  5.958843  8.695228  8.556889  6.137504
0-2  6.329124  9.084011  6.923625  4.145677  5.632268  8.421644  9.479982  6.228819
1-1  7.116864  8.865733  7.795066  4.832890  5.289097  8.994071  8.355792  6.705978
1-2  6.898450  8.792790  7.941341  5.061776  5.741467  8.657854  9.210915  6.982994
2-1  7.224002  8.910793  7.991522  5.053111  5.402586  8.757223  8.178914  6.556123
2-2  6.993221  8.978710  8.093286  5.026800  5.812498  8.868823  8.981567  6.852998
4-1  7.266787  9.261390  8.396177  5.251719  6.133399  9.241745  7.596935  7.074677
4-2  7.483816  9.300124  8.137504  5.551516  5.794416  9.110092  7.914684  6.904484
```

Comment: I cannot see the data. You should try to add the picture again.

Comment: Simulation implies some model. If you want bootstrap, try approach described in this article:http://www.jstatsoft.org/v29/i05/paper.

Comment: I'd fixed the formatting for you and you've now re-broken it...